# Disable Free Shipping based on shipping classes in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to write a function for WooCommerce that will disable free shipping if a product with a certain shipping class is present in the cart.

Here is what I have which is not working.  e-packet is the shipping class that should disable free shipping if it is present in the cart.

```
function hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart( $rates, $package ) {

    $shipping_classes = array('e-packet');
    $if_exists = false;

    foreach( $package['contents'] as $key => $values ) {
        if( in_array( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes )   )
            $if_exists = true;
    }

    if( $if_exists ) unset( $rates['free_shipping:9'] );

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar: [Unsetting WooCommerce shipping method based on cart items shipping classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068536/unsetting-woocommerce-shipping-method-based-on-cart-items-shipping-classes/45069590#45069590)

I have make very small changes. This code is tested and works *(see the note at the end)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart', 100, 2 );
function hide_shipping_when_class_is_in_cart( $rates, $package ) {
    // Initialisation 
    $free_shipping_method = 'free_shipping:9';
    $shipping_classes = array('e-packet');
    $class_exists = false;

    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item )
        if( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class(),  $shipping_classes ) ) {
            $class_exists = true;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }

    if( $class_exists )
        unset( $rates[$free_shipping_method] );

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

> **You should need to refresh the shipping caches:** 
>   1) First this code is already saved on your function.php file. 
>   2) In Shipping settings, enter in a Shipping Zone and disable a **Shipping Method** and "save". Then re-enable that **Shipping Method** and "save". **You are done.**